# Expected LdrDoDebuggerBreak(), got NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory()

Tags: windbg, callstack

During a debugging workshop, one of the participants could not follow an example.

When running an executable under WinDbg 10.0.15603.137 on his Windows 10 machine, the debugger was breaking the first time at `NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory()` instead of the initial breakpoint in `LdrDoDebuggerBreak()`.

When trying to run the executable with `g`, it says that there's no debugee to run. What could the problem have been?

Here's what it looked like:

[image: Screenshot]

The source code of the application is trivial:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <exception>

int _tmain(int /*argc*/, _TCHAR* /*argv*/[])
{
    throw std::exception();
}
```

Note: I'll hardly be able to provide additional information, since I have no more access to the customer's PC and it doesn't happen on mine.

Comment: Well, it didn't really break. It's a lie about an already exited process. I don't know what happened, but I can tell you what you should have done. Break at process creation instead of at the initial breakpoint and step/trace/go/whatever from there. I described how to do this in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42046071/306930

Comment: @conio: usually, the initial breakpoint is enough for the analysis I want to do. Interesting approach. If I have the chance to analyze the issue with your approach, I'll probably find out why it terminated before the initial breakpoint.

Comment: Well, sure. I don't suggest have it the default behavior. You're right that usually you don't need it. Process termination before the ibp is pretty much the textbook example of why you would need it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to say for sure what the problem was, but we can say what the problem *could* have been. Luckily that's what you asked.

I can't assign exact probabilities to this, but it's quite likely that an implicitly linked DLL failed loading. That's the major thing that happens before the initial breakpoint<sup>1</sup>.

Why did a DLL failed to load? Maybe some kind of resource problem, but - especially assuming you tried running a "fresh" machine after a restart - somewhat more likely is an extra DLL being loaded on the problematic machine. Maybe an AVRF DLL, maybe an AppInit DLL, maybe one of a hundred other ways to inject DLLs into unknowing and unwilling processes<sup>2</sup>.

As I said in my comment, the way to find out for sure would have been having WinDBG break on process creation rather than on the initial breakpoint, and start debugging from there.

The way to do this is to start NTSD/CDB with `-xe cpr`, setting this in WinDBG's *Event Filters* window (accessible through the *Debug* menu), or using `sxe cpr` and `.restart` in WinDBG, assuming you started the process in WinDBG (rather than attached to it), which is the best easiets and best in my opinion, but that's a matter of taste.

---

<sup>1</sup> I think TLS callbacks for the main modules are also executed before the initial breakpoint, but what are the chances someone messes with the project configuration or the CRT LIBs to add a problematic TLS callback? (TLS callbacks of the implicitly linked DLLs are included in "DLL loading".)

<sup>2</sup> But again, the more nefarious and clever tricks are less common and thus less likely.

Comment: Thanks. With this information, I compared the ModLoad events to a "typical" run that "works" and stops at the initial breakpoint. In addition to my screenshot, I see `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSVCR110.dll` in the list of modules. So to me, it sounds like that participant has not compiled the sources by himself and ran an executable for which he did not have the C runtime installed. Does that sound plausible?

Comment: @ThomasWeller: It's possible, though in that case I think I would expect the [MessageBox about a missing import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85ZJM.png). I also assumed that the participant used the same machine to build and run, but maybe I shouldn't have had. :)